# Creating tmp variables inside a list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I have the following list comprehensions that I would like to optimize and turn into one single list comprehension, but I can't figure out how to handle the shifts:

```
lines = [line for line in lines if len(line) > 55]
shifts = [int(int(line.split()[1]) >= 1000000)+int(int(line.split()[4]) >= 100000) for line in lines]
xyz = [(float(line[30+s:38+s]),float(line[38+s:46+s]),float(line[46+s:54+s])) for s,line in zip(shifts,lines)]
```

I know it should look something like this combined:

```
xyz = [(float(line[30 + s:38 + s]), float(line[38 + s:46 + s]), float(line[46 + s:54 + s])) for line in lines if len(line) > 55]
```

but I still need to add/define the s variable in some way. I suspect I can use the walrus operator for it, but I'm not actually sure, since I do not really want to test the condition s, but just want to assign it.
So the following doesn't work for instance, since s is used as a condition and sometimes s == 0, which means it is cutting away examples where the shift is zero, which is not what I want:

```
xyz = [(float(line[30 + s:38 + s]), float(line[38 + s:46 + s]), float(line[46 + s:54 + s])) for line in lines if len(line) > 55 and (s := int(int(line.split()[1]) >= 1000000)+int(int(line.split()[4]) >= 100000))]
```

I could of course just use the definition of s in all the position instead of s, but that seems ugly and inefficient. So is there a better way of doing this?

Edit:
I need this code to be as fast as possible, which is why I have it in list comprehension form rather than loop form, and also why I want to combine the 3 list comprehensions into one.

A similar code in loop form looks like this:

```
for line in lines:
    shift = 0
    dat = line.strip('\n')
    data = dat.split()
    if len(dat) > 55:
        if int(data[4]) >= 100000:
            shift += 1
        if int(data[1]) >= 1000000:
            shift += 1
        x = float(dat[30+shift:38+shift])
        y = float(dat[38+shift:46+shift])
        z = float(dat[46+shift:54+shift])
        X.append(x)
        Y.append(y)
        Z.append(z)
    else:
        continue
```

I understand that my example isn't the easiest to understand, but what I want is essentially the following in comprehension form

```
for line in lines:
    s = g(line)
    result = (f1(line,s),f2(line,s),f3(line,s))
```

where g,f1,f2,f3 are some non-important functions. So the essential is that s is a function on line, but because I need it several times in the output, I want to temporarily save it as a variable such that I don't have to compute it several times. However, I don't know how to do this during a list comprehension.

Comment: Using complex list comprehension make your code totaly unreadable. If you can't understant what a list comprehension does when you look a it, it propably not the best way...

Comment: You can possibly do it using the walrus operator, but it makes it more confusing. Use an ordinary loop or call a function in the list comprehension.

Comment: The code started off being written in a for loop, but I need a highly optimized version, hence the list comprehension. I don't care whether the code is more confusing. I need to run this code on about a million files each with about a million lines of code. And my current list comprehension version is already faster than the for loop version by about 5x, but I should be able to make it even faster by combining the lists into one single list comprehension I suspect

Comment: @Tue list comprehensions **are not optimizations**. I repeat, list comprehensions *sole purpose* is for readability/expressiveness. Use a for-loop. If you put it inside a function, and cache the `list.append` method resolution, it should be pretty much as fast as the list comprehension. e.g. use `append_to_list = result.append` outside the loop then use `append_to_list(item)` in the loop (instead of `result.append(item)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I tested what you said, but my results seem to indicate that this is not the case. The loop method you suggest is almost twice as slow as the tripple list comprehension. As shown below. Do you see anything I have done wrong in the comparison?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ["idiom for assignment a temporary variable in comprehensions"](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.9.html#optimizations) that CPython 3.9 even optimized to be a simple assignment, used for `split` and for `s`:

```
xyz = [(float(line[30+s:38+s]),
        float(line[38+s:46+s]),
        float(line[46+s:54+s]))
       for line in lines
       if len(line) > 55
       for split in [line.split()]
       for s in [(int(split[1]) >= 1000000) +
                 (int(split[4]) >= 100000)]]
```

And the whole thing spread over multiple short lines like this is pretty readable, in my opinion.

Btw I got rid of the explicit `bool`-to-`int` conversions. When you add two `bool`s, you get an int anyway (e.g., `True + True` is `2`) and it's [much faster](https://tio.run/##PY5NDgIhDIX3nOJtJoDOxrAxGm/hfsLEjrLgJx1ceHoswdgE2n59r1A@9ZWTOxdubeMcUUOkUBFiyVzBVMhXpXbcoL1cq5w7v@mKkOoijSSttsxYpAT79CTj7EVBomPqWKxHrHqGFrnxVrperPaHlj9bOhzuHlVeiCGZ8Q9DM3Zr/9PCfYue3ANpBzQmmIoDTuTsDBrCIbKtfQE) (though might not matter much in your overall code).

Comment: I tested this method, and while you do make it into a single list comprehension, it is done by adding additional for statements, the code is slowed down significantly, such that it is actually the slowest of the 3 methods I tested below.

Comment: @Tue Can you please include some test data (or some code that generates test data) in the question? Should be there anyway. I'm very surprised by your timings and would like to investigate this. I.e., I'd like to run your benchmark myself and play around with it, but I need data for that. (Ideally I'd have your actual file, but I don't expect that.)

Comment: I just zipped and uploaded the file I tested it on here: https://easyupload.io/d5gvw9 The link should work for 30 days I believe

Answer (score 0):

**Update** The results that I posted yesterday were not replicable today, I'm not sure what went wrong yesterday, but here are the new results, which are also consistent with what Kelly got.

Based on the different suggestions I made a comparison:

```
import numpy as np
import time
def get_origo_and_basis_vectors_old(file_pdb_in):
    with open(file_pdb_in, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()[1:]
    xyz = []
    XYZapp = xyz.append
    for line in lines:
        data = line.split()
        if len(line) > 55:
            shift = (int(data[4]) >= 100000) + (int(data[1]) >= 1000000)
            XYZapp((float(line[30+shift:38+shift]),float(line[38+shift:46+shift]),float(line[46+shift:54+shift])))
        else:
            continue
    XYZ = np.asarray(xyz)
    origo = np.mean(XYZ,axis=0)
    basisvectors = np.max(XYZ,axis=0) - np.min(XYZ,axis=0)
    return origo, basisvectors


def get_origo_and_basis_vectors(file_pdb_in):
    with open(file_pdb_in, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()[1:]
    lines = [line for line in lines if len(line) > 55]
    shifts = [(int(line.split()[1]) >= 1000000)+(int(line.split()[4]) >= 100000) for line in lines]
    xyz = [(float(line[30+s:38+s]),float(line[38+s:46+s]),float(line[46+s:54+s])) for s,line in zip(shifts,lines)]
    XYZ = np.asarray(xyz)
    origo = np.mean(XYZ,axis=0)
    basisvectors = np.max(XYZ,axis=0) - np.min(XYZ,axis=0)
    return origo, basisvectors



def get_origo_and_basis_vectors_new(file_pdb_in):
    with open(file_pdb_in, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()[1:]
    xyz = [(float(line[30 + s:38 + s]),
            float(line[38 + s:46 + s]),
            float(line[46 + s:54 + s]))
           for line in lines
           if len(line) > 55
           for split in [line.split()]
           for s in [(int(split[1]) >= 1000000) +
                     (int(split[4]) >= 100000)]]
    XYZ = np.asarray(xyz)
    origo = np.mean(XYZ,axis=0)
    basisvectors = np.max(XYZ,axis=0) - np.min(XYZ,axis=0)
    return origo, basisvectors

if __name__=='__main__':
    file = '/media/tue/Data/Data/test_mini/relax_pdb/calc/AF_1W_1WU_1WUZ_1_A/leap/AF_1W_1WU_1WUZ_1_A_neutral.pdb'

    t0=time.time()
    for i in range(10):
        oo2, aa2 = get_origo_and_basis_vectors_new(file)
    print(f"1 list comprehension {time.time()-t0:2.2f}s")


    t0=time.time()
    for i in range(10):
        oo, aa = get_origo_and_basis_vectors(file)
    print(f"3 list comprehensions {time.time()-t0:2.2f}s")

    t0=time.time()
    for i in range(10):
        oo3, aa3 = get_origo_and_basis_vectors_old(file)
    print(f"for loop {time.time()-t0:2.2f}s")
```

From which I got the following timings:

```
1 list comprehension 11.81s
3 list comprehensions 12.71s
for loop 11.87s
```

So the 1 list comprehension and the for loop both seem to be slightly faster than the 3 list comprehension, which is consistent with what people were telling me.

Comment: @KellyBundy this was run with python 3.9.7

Comment: I don't believe I was running anything else yesterday when I tested it, but I have also been unable to repeat the results today, and it seems like they all run much faster today with speeds around 1.1 s for basically all of them (3 comps being slightly slower for me as well)
I tested it in all the different ways I could think of, but they all agreed with this.
Sorry for the misinformation yesterday.

Comment: Ok, good :-). Btw, unless you have good reason to include them in the timing, I'd take out the reading of the file and the NumPy part. And if you want some further microoptimizations, you could use more local variables, like in the function do `float_ = float` and then use that instead.